# LCG in MatLab implementation

Tags: matlab, lcg

hi im having trouble creating a linear congruential generator in MatLab, the ones that I found online work quite different than mine.  then im trying to print values of the m and a (relatively prime, m being a large prime obviously) and check when the cycle is full.  I know all the math stuff, im getting used to matlab and its hard to implement this for me even though i should know.  my program looks like this:

```
M = [];
    for m = 100:10000;
        M(m) = m;

    A = [];
    for a = 2:(m-1);
    A(a) = a;
    B = [];
    R = [];
    for n = 1:1000;
    R(n) = n;
    B(n) = A(a) * n;
    K = [];
            K(n)=mod(B(n),M(m));
    n=n+1;
    a=a+1;
    m=m+1;
    if K(n) == R(n)
        print (m)   
        print (a)
        print ('the cycle is done')
    end

    end
end
end
```

also im not too familiar with MatLab so im probably creating arrays the wrong way.  thanks in advance.

Comment: So how exactly does your output not match what you expect? Can you elaborate? Does it run at all?

Comment: it doesnt run at all, i know what i wanna do i cant implement it in matlab.  i want to create a matrix with column A, M, B(which is A*n(seed)) and BmodM.  then want to compare the BmodMs to n(seed).  if theyre equal i need to get all the values of M and A.  if not n=n+1, a=a+1, m=m+1.

Answer (score 0):

Well you aren't really asking a question there. Here is some advice for you:

1) Pre-allocate the matrices: M = zeros(9900,1), A = zeros(9998,1), you will get much faster results when you loop, or even better M = 100:10000 works directly if the values you want to put in are as simple as that.

2) You do not need to do the a = a+1, the for loop does it automatically for you (unless it's there for another reason I'm unaware of).

Comment: R = zeros(10000,10000); 
n = zeros(5000,1);
 M = zeros(5000,1);
    for m = 150:5000;
        M(m) = m;
        
    a = zeros(m,1);
        for n = 1:5000;
        R(n) = n;
        
            B = zeros(10000,1);
            for a = 2:m-1;
            B = (a*R);

                K = zeros(10000,1);
                K(B,M)=mod(B,M);
    

    if K(B,M) == Ro
        print (M)   
        print (a)
        print ('the cycle is done')
    end
            end
        end
    end